# Why Redux need two times dispatch

Tags: react-redux

The following is my App.js

```
class Root extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(actions.getTable((data) => {
          console.log(data)
    }));
  }
}
```

Then the following is my action.js:

```
export function getTable(callback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get({
      api: 'localhost/test',
    })
      .then((list) => {
        callback(list.data)
        dispatch({
          type: RECEIVE_TABLE_DATA,
          data: list.data,
        });
      })
  };
}
```

As my understanding the data had already been dispatched to Reducer in action.js, such as:

```
dispatch({
  type: RECEIVE_TABLE_DATA,
  data: list.data,
});
```

then, why the data was dispatched again in App.js, such as:

```
dispatch(actions.getTable((data) => {
      console.log(data)
}));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the second part of the question? What is the problem there?

Comment: there is no problem, I just could not understand the data had already been dispatched in action.js, why dispatch was called again in App.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code, I'm assuming you are using `redux-thunk`. With `redux-thunk`, you can use a `thunk`, which is a function that can dispatch other actions, which is useful when dealing with async activity. A thunk can also be dispatched as a regular action.

For example, in your code, `getTable` is an action creator which returns a `thunk`. That's why it can dispatch the `RECEIVE_TABLE_DATA` action. Notice it could dispatch another action, such as `FETCH_TABLE_DATA` before the axios call for example.

So this code

```
dispatch(actions.getTable((data) => {
    console.log(data)
}));
```

dispatch a thunk. It does not dispatch the data again.

If you remove

```
dispatch({
  type: RECEIVE_TABLE_DATA,
  data: list.data,
});
```

from the `getTable` function, the data won't be dispatched at all.

I recommend you read the documentation from https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk or the async example from the redux doc. In this file for example https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/actions/index.js you can see the difference between a regular action creator such as `requestPosts` or `receivePosts`, and a thunk action creator such as `fetchPosts`. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Nice explanation, I just learned Thunk this middleware from you, thanks!